# Does sort alter my json array or does it return a sorted array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I am trying to sort a json array on my Table header click. I am trying to follow this web [article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/03/sortable-tables-react/). My function runs but the array is never changed. Here is the function:

```
function setInvoiceSortField(field) {
    console.log(field);
    let sortedInvoices = this.state.invoiceList;
    if (field !== null) {
        sortedInvoices.sort((a, b) => {
            console.log(`a ${a[field]}`);
            console.log(`b ${b[field]}`);
            if (a[field] < b[field]) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (a[field] > b[field]) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        });
        this.setState({ invoiceList: sortedInvoices });
    }
}
```

I can post an example of the json array and/or the entire .js file if needed. Is `.sort()` changing `sortedInvoices` or does it return a sorted array? Any hints or help are extremely appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I added an if to check to see if they match post sort and they do.

```
function setInvoiceSortField(field) {
    console.log(field);
    let sortedInvoices = this.state.invoiceList;
    if (field !== null) {
        sortedInvoices.sort((a, b) => {
            console.log(`a ${a[field]}`);
            console.log(`b ${b[field]}`);
            if (a[field] < b[field]) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (a[field] > b[field]) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        });
        if (sortedInvoices === this.state.invoiceList) {
            console.log("matched")
        }
        this.setState({ invoiceList: sortedInvoices });
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps (this is a guess) React sees that your array in the state update is the same array that's already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are directly assigning the array(this.state.invoiceList) to sortedInvoices it will be done by reference. So even though your array(sortedInvoices) is different from invoiceList, both the references are same. Hence changes are not reflected.

```
function setInvoiceSortField(field) {
console.log(field);
let sortedInvoices = [...this.state.invoiceList];
if (field !== null) {
    sortedInvoices.sort((a, b) => {
        console.log(`a ${a[field]}`);
        console.log(`b ${b[field]}`);
        if (a[field] < b[field]) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (a[field] > b[field]) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
    this.setState({ invoiceList: sortedInvoices });
  }
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. What a stupid mistake on my part.

Answer (score 3):

From the [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place, and returns the sorted array. Example copied.

```
const months = ['March', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Dec'];
months.sort();
console.log(months);
// expected output: Array ["Dec", "Feb", "Jan", "March"]
```

Comment: But this doesn't answer why the array is never changed.

Comment: This didn't fix my problem but it did answer the question I did ask. +1